# Adding a webview programmatically

Tags: java, layout, webview

I have had no trouble adding a web view to my layout on click with a button, but when it comes to adding a web view on create of my main activity it just does nothing. I need the program to create certain web views based on data stored when I run it. It just really gets me that the same exact code runs perfectly when I put it inside an onClick button, but in the main method it does absolutely nothing. No error, no anything.

```
    tickerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.TickerLinearLayout);

    currency = new WebView(this);
           currency.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, btcUp.getMeasuredHeight()));
           tickerLinearLayout.addView(currency);
           currency.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           disableScroll(currency);

           currency.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/btc.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a Webview programatically in an Activity, you will first have to add your Webview into a RelativeLayout. I am choosing a RelativeLayout because my use case needs the Webview to be positioned on different locations on the Parent View time to time.

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

        private WebView mWebView;

        public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mWebView = new WebView(context);
            mWebView.setId(View.NO_ID);
            mWebView.setScrollContainer(false);
            mWebView.loadData("<html><body>TEST</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            mWebView.setLayoutParams(params);
            addView(mWebView);
        }

        public WebView getTheWebView() {
            return mWebView;
        }
    }
```

You can modify the CustomRelativeLayout class to accept URL.

In your MainActivity class, you will have to add a new instance of CustomRelativeLayout and add it to the contentView as shown below:

```
setContentView(new CustomRelativeLayout(this));
```

To make adjustments to the size of the webview play around with the width and height of the LayoutParams added to the Webview.

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        <width>, <height>);
```